# How to share Salesforce Einstein models between few accounts

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, salesforce, salesforce-einstein

I started to work with Salesforce Einstein API, in particular with Einstein Intent & Sentiment analysis, and I faced an issue - when I created new models under one of my account, I couldn't see these models under my other account. I checked out the official documentation & tried to research a bit, but I didn't find any ways how I can share Einstein models between several accounts. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about or related to programing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According discussion with Artificial Intelligence Product Leader at Salesforce сurrently sharing models involves retraining the model with the new org. But they are thinking through ways to improve model sharing though.